# Form Height and Width in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, resize, ui-design

I am developing MS Access front end, where I have many forms. Most of the users in the company are using 15-17 inch laptop.

What should be the size of the form. More particularly what should be the `Height` and `Width` property of the form.

I am using the base line methodology, so will be considering the 15 inch laptop as base and develop the forms, so that they don't have to use the scroll bars for the navigation in single form.

I tries searching for correlation between the Screen size and Forms Size in MS Access, but could not find any resource.

Other best practice for forms Height and Width will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: DoCmd.MoveSize should deal with this.

Comment: Does your company have any standards regarding screen resolution (i.e. 1024X768 versus 640X480)? Worry more about the resolution than the size of the monitor. Let;s just assume your app needs to be full screen. Please Google: access form scale size to screen    and you will find many references and suggestions. There is code available to resize controls and fonts to account for different screens. Best to design for lower resolution, then it's easy to fit for higher resolution.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I check with IT hardware team. 95% Desktop monitors are 1360x768 or 1366 X 768 i.e. 720P. So for this resolution what will be the ideal form Width and Height?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late on this, but you should be designing with Layout and Anchoring to allow for a flexible form that can resize dependent on the size of the screen.